# How to Pass Interface Object to a Method

Tags: java

I have a main class as shown below. I want to Pass interface object to another method from Main method. I am Passing it as shown in my Main class below. But I am getting error "; expected". Can some one please help me?

This is my Main Class :

```
package com.armus.web.server;
import com.armus.common.dtflow.DfService;
public class TriggerAgain
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Long i= 97944605L;
        DMSerImpl rdf = new DMSerImpl();
        try {
            /*********** Section start....Getting Problem In this section...How Can I Pass interface object to a method setDfService*********/
            @Override
            rdf.setDfService(new DfService()
            {
                Dfsessn dfsessn=getDfsessnById(i)
                {
                    System.out.println("In main class...In interface method="+i);
                }
            })
            /*************************************************Section End*******************************************************************/
            com.armus.dto.Jinfo a=rdf.Trigger(i);
        }
        catch( Throwable   e){
            System.out.println("In exception = "+e+" "+i);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;            // Always must return something
        }
    }
}
```

This is my another class to which I want to Pass interface Object to "setDfService" Method.

```
package com.armus.web.server;

import com.armus.common.dtflow.DfService;
import com.armus.common.dto.Dfsessn;
import com.armus.foundation.client.exception.ServiceException;
import com.armus.dto.Jinfo;


public class DMSerImpl
  extends Remoteservletsup
  implements DMserv, DMAjxSer
{
  private DfService dtflowser;

  public void setDfService(DfService dtflowser)
  {
    this.dtflowser = dtflowser;
  }

  private Dfsessn getDfsessn(long sessionId)
    throws ServiceException
  {
    try
    {
      dfSession = this.dtflowser.getDfsessnById(Long.valueOf(sessionId));
    }
    catch (ServerException e)
    {
      Dfsessn dfSession;
      LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
    }
        return dfSession;
  }

  public com.armus.dto.Jinfo Trigger(long sessionId)
    throws ServiceException
  {
       Dfsessn dfSession = getDfsessn(sessionId);
        //some code
  }
}
```

Below is My Interface :

```
package com.armus.common.dtflow;

import com.armus.common.dto.Dfsessn;
import com.armus.common.exception.ServerException;

public abstract interface DfService
{
  public abstract Dfsessn getDfsessnById(Long paramLong)
    throws ServerException;
}
```

Thank you in Advance !!! :)

Comment: What line is identified by the error message?

Comment: By "interface object", I assume you mean "instance of an anonymous class".  When you make that instance, you need to specify which method(s) you're overriding.  I suggest you look online for examples of the use of anonymous classes to see how they work, because your attempt is quite far from what's required.

Comment: Not sure...I am new to java...am I doing it right?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of `setDfService()`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of creating an instance of an anonymous class

```
    rdf.setDfService(new DfService() {
    @Override
    public Dfsessn getDfsessnById(Long paramLong) {
           ....
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are:

1. Putting the `@Override` in the wrong place;
2. not declaring the method override properly; and
3. missing a closing semicolon:

   ```
   rdf.setDfService(new DfService()
   {
       @Override
       public Dfsessn getDfsessnById(Long i)
       {
           System.out.println("In main class...In interface method="+i);
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
        @Override
        rdf.setDfService(new DfService()
        {
            Dfsessn dfsessn=getDfsessnById(i)
            {
                System.out.println("In main class...In interface method="+i);
            }
        })
```

Above what you are trying to do is creating an anonymous class instance implementing the `DfService` interface but you are not doing it correctly(syntax wise).

Read about anonymous inner classes here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anonymous-inner-class-java/

Also, `DfService` is a functional interface(single method interface) so you can also use a lamda here. Something like this.

```
rdf.setDfService(paramLong -> System.out.println("In main class...In interface method="+i));
```

Take a look at this for more info https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-use-lambda-expression-in-place-anonymous-class-java8.html